# Why does Ltac not match the clause?

Tags: coq, ltac

In the following Coq proof:

```
Ltac easy_ltac t  := match goal with
  | [Z: @eq nat t ?Y |- _ ] => pose ?Y as N 
  end.

Lemma easy: forall (n: nat), (n >= O)%nat.
Proof.
intros n. destruct n eqn: M.  easy_ltac n.
```

I get the error message: "No matching clauses for match.", while I have the hypothesis

```
M : @eq nat n O
```

I do not understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is the extraneous `?` before the 2nd occurrence of `Y`.

Also just to recall, you might want to use the `fresh` tactic rather than hard-coded `N` as an hypothesis name.

So, it should work if you just write:

```
Ltac easy_ltac t := match goal with
  | [Z: @eq nat t ?Y |- _ ] => let N := fresh "N" in pose Y as N
  end.

Lemma easy: forall (n: nat), (n >= O)%nat.
Proof.
intros n. destruct n eqn: M. easy_ltac n. easy_ltac n.
```